# What type is the subscriber in Observable.create((subscriber) => { ... }) in angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

I've been pulling my hair out on this one. Has anyone figured out what type the subscriber is in the Angular 2 typescript code block below?

```
let obs: Observable<string> = Observable.create((subscriber) => { ... })
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create is for creating `Observables` with custom subscription behaviors.

The function that you pass to the `Observable.create` method defines the behavior that should occur when the Observable is subscribed to. Thus, the `subscriber` that is passed in would be an object that implements the `Observer<T>` interface.

For instance, the following code would create an `Observable` that when subscribed to, would emit two values and then complete (apologies in advance for any syntax errors, I don't use TypeScript):

```
let obs: Observable<string> = Observable.create((subscriber) => { 
  subscriber.next("Hello");
  subscriber.next("World!");
  subscriber.complete();
});

//Here is a subscriber that we define to subscribe to the Observable
let sub: Subscriber<string> = Subscriber.create(
              (x) => console.log(x),
              null,
              () => console.log("Done"));

//At this point the method you passed to Observable.create will be invoked
obs.subscribe(sub);

//Output:
//Hello 
//World!
//Done
```

Note that this does not actually *execute* this code, instead you are defining behavior that will be followed when a new Subscriber subscribes by calling
`obs.subscribe(subscriber)`
Or with a function:
`obs.subscribe((x) => console.log(x);`

In many cases the use of `create` is not necessary as there are wrappers for most of the common event emission sources so you don't have

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for the detailed explanation. But I can't seem to find an Observer<T> interface. Plus I also don't know what the T will be. So I guess I'll have to leave the observer as "any" for now. Thanks for the help! ;0)

Regards,

Comment: @Zorthgo `Subscriber<T>` implements the `Observer<T>` interface. `<T>` in this case would be `string` since that is the type that you are using.

Comment: Thanks Paul. But I was able to import Observable from the Angular2 library, but there doesn't seem to be any Observer object that I can import.

Comment: Just for the sake of leaving notes. In the end, I could not find an Observer<T> interface, so I settled for using an EventEmitter<string>. Seems to work fine. :)

Comment: As of `"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",` it seems that `Observer<string>` would be the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

> Has anyone figured out what type the subscriber is in the Angular 2 typescript code block below

It is the `next` value whenever it becomes available. See : http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/create.html `onNext` is the function `(subscriber)=>`. Personally I would call it `(next)=>`